# Could Higgs Bosons (Higgs Field) be used to increase the mass of photons?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, hard-science

I've heard the the Higgs Boson is responsible for the mass of *most* elementary particles.

If so... couldn't a Higgs Boson/Higgs Field be used to increase the mass of a photon? and how would it affect the field of Particle Physics?

P.S. please forgive my mistakes when it comes to the terminology used with this question (I am not particularly familiar with the field of particle physics).

P.P.S. No HANDWAVING

Comment: You should read up on electroweak symmetry breaking and how the 4 original particles remix into our photon and others. The others *do* have mass via Higgs, so this is what you should look into. But I won’t elaborate because of your “no handwaving” clause.  As asked, Cort has the only answer: the photon doesn’t do that.

Comment: Higgs boson is a force carrier for mass just like photon is for electromagnetic force and just humor me graviton is for gravitational force, BTW your question doesn't seems suitable for worldbuilding to me...

Answer (score 7):

**No**

If you asked for no-handwaving, that's the end of the answer.  In the standard model, a photon is a massless particle.  The W and Z bosons, which have mass, are believed to have mass like properties because of symmetry breaking in the Higgs field.  The photon is not affected by this.

You're free to invent a different quantum physics in which the photon is affected by the Higgs field, but that would be handwaving.